Error in back reference with roman numbers
I have a problem that's been irritating me for a week, and I don't know what is causing it.
Each of my references has a back reference that indicates on which page it was with a hyperlink to back to the page:

However, one of my references is on a page with a roman number (iii), and the output is wrong:

When it should just be: (Cited on page ↑iii)
Here is the code to experience the problem, that only arise when the page is iii as you'll see:
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@article{buterin_combining_2020,
  author       = {Vitalik Buterin and
                  Diego Hernandez and
                  Thor Kamphefner and
                  Khiem Pham and
                  Zhi Qiao and
                  Danny Ryan and
                  Juhyeok Sin and
                  Ying Wang and
                  Yan X. Zhang},
  title        = {Combining {GHOST} and Casper},
  journal      = {CoRR},
  volume       = {abs/2003.03052},
  year         = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[backref=page,colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}

\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
  \ifcase #1 %
    (Not cited.)%
  \or
    (Cited on page~#2)%
  \else
    (Cited on pages~#2)%
  \fi%
}
\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ and~}
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, and~}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\backrefxxx}[3]{%
  \ifx#1\relax%
    \ifx#2\relax%
    \else%
      \hyperlink{cite.#2}{\textcolor{blue}{$\uparrow$~#1}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \hyperlink{cite.#2}{\textcolor{blue}{$\uparrow$~#1}}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{mycite}
% Redefine \cite to include an anchor
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{mycite}%
  \hypertarget{cite.\themycite}{}%
  \oldcite{#1}%
}


\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\section{Example}

Here is an example of a citation with roman numbers \cite{goossens93}.

\newpage
Here is an example of a citation with arabic numbers \cite{buterin_combining_2020}.

\newpage
Here is an example of a citation with arabic numbers \cite{buterin_combining_2020}.

\newpage
Here is an example of a citation with arabic numbers \cite{buterin_combining_2020}.


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Here is an example of a citation with arabic numbers \cite{buterin_combining_2020}.


\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}


As mentioned I redefined \cite to include an anchor so that the backreference goes back to exact place of the citation.
If you have any clue on how to remove the useless i in the quote I'd love to. Even if it necessitates handling this citation separately from the rest, anything !!
Here is a longer example of when the bug arrives:


you should provide an example that shows the problem, not just a fragment, but \ifx#1\relax% tests if the first two tokens of #1 are equal and typesets the remaining ones if they are (and similarly the test with #2) so if #2 is iii then \ifx#2\relax is true and will typeset i being the third i after the first two are consumed by the test. I guess that is where your i comes from

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thank you for your comment, @DavidCarlisle. I added the necessary code to try it. The error only exists for the Roman page iii, which I don't understand. I must say your comment seems to be on the right track, but I am not sure I understand how to fix it still

I can't test now but I would guess it fails on page 11 or 22 or iix as well as iii, but you don't say why you have those definitions or what you intended them to do

No page 11 and 22 work, xviii works however xii bugs...

I found the solution! The code for backrefxxx should be the following:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\backrefxxx}[3]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax
    % #1 is empty, do nothing
  \else
    \hyperlink{cite.#2}{\textcolor{blue}{$\uparrow$~#1}}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

The problem was that just testing \ifx#1\relax% was not exactly verifying that #1 was empty, but rather that the first two tokens of #1 are equal and typesets the remaining ones as mentioned by @DavidCarlisle.

\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax is safer.

The test for emptiness of #1 or #2 is wrong: when #1 starts with two equal tokens (for instance iii) the test would return true.
Here's a simpler coding using expl3.
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@article{buterin_combining_2020,
  author       = {Vitalik Buterin and
                  Diego Hernandez and
                  Thor Kamphefner and
                  Khiem Pham and
                  Zhi Qiao and
                  Danny Ryan and
                  Juhyeok Sin and
                  Ying Wang and
                  Yan X. Zhang},
  title        = {Combining {GHOST} and Casper},
  journal      = {CoRR},
  volume       = {abs/2003.03052},
  year         = {2020},
}

@article{empty,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2024},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[backref=page,colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ and~}
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, and~}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\backrefalt}{mmmm}
 {
  \int_case:nnF {#1}
   {
    {0}{(Not~cited.)}
    {1}{(Cited~on~page\nobreakspace #2)}
   }
   {(Cited~on~pages\nobreakspace #2)}
 }

\RenewDocumentCommand{\backrefxxx}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnF { \tl_if_blank_p:n {#1} } { \tl_if_blank_p:n {#2} }
   {
    \hyperlink{cite.#2}{\textcolor{blue}{$\uparrow$\nobreakspace #1}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{mycite}
\AddToHook{cmd/cite/before}{\refstepcounter{mycite}\hypertarget{cite.\themycite}{}}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}



\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\nocite{*}

\section{Example}

Here is an example of a citation with roman numbers \cite{goossens93}.

\newpage
Here is an example of a citation with arabic numbers \cite{buterin_combining_2020}.

\newpage
Here is an example of a citation with arabic numbers \cite{buterin_combining_2020}.

\newpage
Here is an example of a citation with arabic numbers \cite{buterin_combining_2020}.


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Here is an example of a citation with arabic numbers \cite{buterin_combining_2020}.


\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}


